# Retrieving a pixel buffer from varying times using CMTimeAdd?

Tags: avfoundation, cmtime

I am currently using a `CADisplayLink` to grab the current pixel buffer from an `AVPlayerItemVideoOutput`.  The display link is updating like so;

```
func displayLinkUpdated(link: CADisplayLink) {

    let time = output.itemTime(forHostTime: CACurrentMediaTime())
    guard output.hasNewPixelBuffer(forItemTime: time), let buffer = output.copyPixelBuffer(forItemTime: time, itemTimeForDisplay: nil) else { return }
    ...
}
```

I would like to use the same `output` to also grab a pixel buffer exactly 1 second ahead.  Since my video is 30fps, I thought I could use `CMTimeMakeWithSeconds` to do the following;

```
func displayLinkUpdated(link: CADisplayLink) {

    let time = output.itemTime(forHostTime: CACurrentMediaTime())
    let timeB = CMTimeAdd(CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(CMTimeGetSeconds(time) + 1, preferredTimescale: time.timescale), time)

    guard output.hasNewPixelBuffer(forItemTime: time), let buffer = output.copyPixelBuffer(forItemTime: time, itemTimeForDisplay: nil) else { return }
    guard let bufferB = output.copyPixelBuffer(forItemTime: timeB, itemTimeForDisplay: nil) else { return }
    ...
}
```

When I attempt to do this, and then perform my `...` post-processing, the playback I experience is incredibly choppy.  If I set `let timeB = time` just for the sake of testing, my post-processing and playback is back to normal and smooth.

Is there any explanation for why this approach would not work, or be more efficient